# Why is this ST-link V2 not pairing with the STM8s MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, programming, st-link, st, stm8

I had connected this circuit like in this schematic using the ST-LINK V2, however I made some changes, I connected the 2 and 3 pins (OSCIN, OSCOUT) to 12pf capacitors (I have no 20pf or higher)
and connected 1uf to VCAP, didn't connect the bottom right part ( USER & WAKE-UP Button)

[image]

however this error message is keeping getting visible to me[image]

Note:

I don't know if my ST-LINK is broken because one of the 5V pins isn't spitting any voltage (however the pin beside it have 5V)

EDIT:
Thanks a lot guys for your help it worked after I resoldered the SWIM pin and it works without the crystal because I used the internal oscillator.

Comment: the `Note:` is vague

Comment: STLink V2 has no 5V output. Either you don't have a real STLink but an unofficial clone, or you have wrong connections. Please tell what exactly you have and how everything is connected and from where 5V comes and how is everything powered up.

Comment: @Justme yes it is a clone version, and everything powered through the ST-LINK from 5 V of the Computer.

Comment: @HazardousVoltage OK so you don't know if your clone is broken because it does not output 5V, and you don't know if the clone supports STM8 MCUs or not, and you don't know if your clone is compatible with your programming software or not. There is a reason you should mention you are using a clone product, although many people don't even realize they are using clone product and when told that they have a clone they just go buy the official product.

Comment: Your schematic has marked the crystal oscillator parts as "not fitted". How do you clock the MCU?

Comment: @thebusybee Please check the edited part in the post.